# Overall accuracy of multiclass classification using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a data frame as shown below.

```
id     label     prediction
1      cat       cat
2      dog       cat
3      cow       dog
4      cow       cow
5      dog       cat
6      cat       cat
7      cat       cat
8      dog       dog
9      dog       dog
10     cat       cat
```

from the above df, I would like to calculate overall accuracy using pandas.

I tried the below code to calculate class-wise accuracy.

```
class_wise_accuracy = (df.groupby('label')['prediction']
                         .value_counts(normalize=True)
                         .unstack(fill_value=0)
                      )

confusion_matrix = (df.groupby('label')['prediction']
                      .value_counts()
                      .unstack(fill_value=0)
                      .reset_index()
                   )
```

Expected Output:

```
overall_accuracy = (4+1+2)/df.shape[0] = 0.7
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use [`crosstab`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.crosstab.html) and the underlying numpy array:

```
a = pd.crosstab(df['label'], df['prediction']).to_numpy()

overall_accuracy = a.diagonal().sum()/a.sum()
```

output: `0.7`

intermediates:

```
pd.crosstab(df['label'], df['prediction'])

prediction  cat  cow  dog
label                    
cat           4    0    0
cow           0    1    1
dog           2    0    2

.tonumpy()

array([[4, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 1],
       [2, 0, 2]])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am facing below issues with the code. AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_numpy'

Comment: which version do you use? Try `.values` instead of `.to_numpy()`

Comment: I am using pandas = 1.0.5

Comment: that's why, `to_numpy` is pandas 1.1.0 ;)